# How to understand glibc cross-reference?

Tags: c, glibc, libc

I am trying to understand how does the hello world program works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Most of it is straightforward, except the `printf` part. I don't know how it works. To understand it, I have looked for [glibc cross reference](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=glibc%20cross%20reference&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=EmhMVuPONuXLyAOBjqHIBw) and found [this page](http://osxr.org/glibc/ident).

Then I searched for `printf` and it returned me lots of [results](http://osxr.org/glibc/ident?_i=printf&_identdefonly=1&_remember=1).

Now which one of these `printf`s my program is using? How can I determine it?

Also, for example when open the [first result](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/libio/bits/stdio2.h#0102) in that page, the function in `printf` function leads me to [__printf_chk](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-printf_chk.c#0005), where the function in `__printf_chk` leads me to [__nldbl___vfprintf_chk](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-compat.c#0583), where the function in `__nldbl___vfprintf_chk` leads me to [__vfprintf_chk](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-compat.c#0583), where the function in `__vfprintf_chk` leads me to again [__nldbl___vfprintf_chk](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-compat.c#0583), which creates an infinite recursion. What's going on?

So in short, how am I supposed to track the source of a given function/source code?

Comment: "Now which one of these printfs my program is using? How can I determine it?" You should figure out how the library is built. This depends mostly on how the compiler is invoked, which is defined in Makefiles. Which are probably just as unreadable. Isn't glibc fun? (Spoiler: glibc isn't fun.)

Comment: Another spoiler: you'll eventually end up in the definition of [vfprintf in stdio-common/vfprintf.c](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#0221), but to see the relationship between that and functions like `__printf`, you'll have to wade through a big soup of preprocessor macros and GCC-specific attribute declarations.

Comment: @Rhymoid Is the reason for all these to create/preserve portability?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but here is my *guess*: there is one generic implementation that is absolutely portable, and then there are some adjustments for platform-specific optimisations (those `__nldbl` functions seem related to systems that have `long double`). To keep this solution *maintainable*, there is some layer of macros and wrapper functions. Over time, this layer grew, and turned into a maintenance burden. (Sadly, such scenarios are pretty common in software engineering.)

Comment: @Rhymoid I see. Then it might be better to find an open source standard library implementation that is much more lightweight.

Comment: Well-known alternatives include musl, uClibc, and dietlibc, compared with glibc [here](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer but I'm unable to leave a comment. It looks like __vfprintf_chk calls vfprintf, which appears to be aliased to _IO_vfprintf_internal in /stdio-common/vfprintf.c. I don't know the origin of the last function, but I can't see the infinite loop here?

Comment: [In this page](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-opt/nldbl-vfprintf_chk.c#0005), `__vfprintf_chk` calls `__nldbl___vfprintf_chk`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Looks like I'm not going to be much help, and I don't know how the recursion you mention is resolved but printf seems to be defined [here](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/stdio-common/printf.c). Finding out which one gets used will require digging into which one gets compiled/linked by the build system, don't know much more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of `printf` is found in [`stdio-common/printf.c`](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/stdio-common/printf.c)

```
int
__printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

which calls [`vfprintf`](http://osxr.org/glibc/source/stdio-common/vfprintf.c)

Comment: How am I supposed to know that it calls _that_ `printf` and not others?

Comment: This is the main part that confuses me. For example, when you look for `vfprintf` in the cross-reference page, you get around a dozen [results](http://osxr.org/glibc/ident?_i=vfprintf) where 3 of them are stated as function definitions. Your link points to 2nd function definition among those results but how am I supposed to know that the 2nd `vprintf` is called and not 2 others?

Comment: There's no easy rule - you might have to check every option. `glibc` is pretty dense because of portability and compatibility requirements. That said, a simple way to weed out some options is to look at the file paths and filenames. `__printf_chk` takes you into the `sysdep` directory - you don't need to go into those types of directories for core implementations.